# Angularjs - $routerProvider's 'when' function and 'templateUrl' navigate to 'wrong' path?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-routing

My dir's structure is like:

```
---/public
      |
      ---index.html
      ---shop.html
      |
      ---/js
          |
          ---index.js
          ---index_controller.js
          ---/lib
          ---/css
          ---/plugins
               |
               ---...
```

my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="signin no-js" lang="">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Flat, Clean, Responsive, application admin template built with bootstrap 3">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<title>Index</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themify-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skins/palette.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts/font.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<script src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/index_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

<script src="plugins/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-primary" ng-app="myApp.index">
    <div class="cover" style="background-image: url(img/cover3.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="overlay bg-primary"></div>
    <div class="center-wrapper">
    <div class="center-content">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <section class="panel bg-white no-b">
            <ul class="switcher-dash-action">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="selected">Index</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="p15" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
                <form role="form" >
                    <div >
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click='testRoute()'>
                            TestRoute
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <p class="text-center">
            Copyright &copy;
            <span id="year" class="mr5"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var el = document.getElementById("year"),
                year = (new Date().getFullYear());
            el.innerHTML = year;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And shop.html renders the following: (*only for test use*):

```
SHOP
```

And index_controller.js is :

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $route, $window) {
  $scope.testRoute = function() {
    console.log(">>>TestRoute>>>");
    $location.url('/shop');
  }
}

function ShopCtrl() {
 console.log("ShopCtrl");
}
```

And index.js:

```
'use strict';
//Angular-js
var module = angular.module('myApp.index', ['ngRoute']);

module.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/shop', {templateUrl: 'shop.html',   controller: ShopCtrl
              });
}]);

/*My Controllers*/
module.
  controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', '$window', IndexCtrl]);

module.
run([
  '$rootScope', '$location',
  function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      var nextTemplate = next.templateUrl;
      var nextController = next.controller;
      console.log("location.path:" + $location.path());
      console.log('Template Starting to leave %s to go to %s\n', "", nextTemplate);
      console.log('Controller Starting to leave %s to go to %s\n', "", nextController);
    });
  }
]);
```

And when I type "http://localhost:6001/index.html" in Chrome's address bar, it renders:
[image]

After clicking Test Route button, it changes to:

[image]

Only the url address changes, and it seems strange:

```
"http://localhost:6001/index.html#/shop"
```

Whereas I need

```
"http://localhost:6001/shop"
```

Chrome's console shows:

[image]

**My problem** is: how to render *shop.html* and how to navigate to `/guoguo` path properly, using code like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/shop', {templateUrl: 'shop.html',   controller: ShopCtrl
                  });
```

I am pretty new to Angular. Maybe I am not thinking in the angularjs approach. Thanks for your points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly get to know that AngularJS is a **SPA(Single Page App)** based framwork. If I simply jump to another html, the page will load another `ng-app`, which has no relation to origin app(*the bootstrap has been restarted*).

What solution I take is to use ng-view inside the `index html`. It allows to load different `ng-view`(which is in '`<div></div>`' from other `html` file), and config the `routeProvider` by declaring `template url` and `controller`.

*I will paste the complete code later, thanks for you all !!!*

Answer (score 0):

It is a mix of issues for your .html# being shown. Try this.

1: Add  in the first line of head tags

```
<head><base href="/"> 
  ...
</head>`
```

2: Use this `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller:'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/about',{
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller:'aboutCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

This should remove the # from the page. But in your server make index.html as the default file serving for the path `http://localhost:6001/` then it will load `http://localhost:6001/index.html` as `http://localhost:6001/`